# Helicon ISAPI Rewrite + ASP.NET : Rewrite rule to redirect to default page?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

How do i rewrite URL like:

http://subfoo.foo.com/ --> http://subfoo.foo.com/Pages/Home.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
RewriteEngine on    
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ Pages/Home.aspx [NC,L]
```